# Download varbinary data from sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a `Varbinary(Max)` column that is basically compressed data.

My page allows users to download this data (after usual user authentication).

It used to work ok, with smaller data size, but now with time, the data is also getting bigger. I am facing lot of problems basically a wait time, before the Save dialog appears.

Code:

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                Response.Buffer = false;
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.ContentType = "application/gzip";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
                + "vbet_1_1.sdf.gz");
                byte[] bytes = (Byte[])reader["backupdata"]; // STUCK HERE
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
```

In the debugger, I can see that

```
byte[] bytes = (Byte[])reader["backupdata"];
```

is where that lag is.

My platform is ASP.Net with .NET Framework 4.0, SQL Server 2008, C# codebehind

Comment: I would suggest to move that data to file system, are there any reason you store data in db? please refer this url for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: i really really wish that, even suggested, but things here take time to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stream the response back. Reading the entire file in memory and then writing it out is not going to scale and you'll start exhasting the server as the number of requests *or* the size of the files increase.

Have a look at [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) and [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/) to see an example of how to do this. As you do not use MVC but straight ASP.NEt you can do it simpler, but the ideas are the same:

- use a streaming API to read the database response (specifically `SqlCommand.ExecuteReade` with [`CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx)) and read the response in chunks, using [`SqlDataReader.GetBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx) (note again the small snipped on MSDN about the importance of `SequentialAccess` flag...)
- use a streaming API to write the HTTP response. [`Response.BinaryWrite()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx) will do.

Comment: yes, i m reading and collecting all information. Thanks, is there a code snippet available ? (the first example looks like a library implementation .. will take time to study)

Answer (score 1):

This is may be helpful:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/gzip ");
Response.OutputStream.Write((Byte[])reader["backupdata"],0,((Byte[])reader["backupdata"]).Length);
```

And you can use filestream tables from sql2012 to directly  storage files

Comment: unfortunately sql 2008 , and Filestream type on varbinary is not allowed , due to security