# Add attachment to Azure DevOps from Sql Server varbinary field

Tags: azure-devops, attachment

Is there a way to get a VARBINARY field from SQL SERVER and attach it to an existing bug in Azure DevOps using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# and ADO.NET, you can read SQL Server database `varbinary` field value to `byte[]`, then you can create stream by using that `byte[]`

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

After that, you can upload this data as attachment to a work item (e.g. bug) like this (`1111` is the work item id, `test.pptx` is just a sample, you should get it from database too)

```
.....//ADO.NET to read varbinary field to byte[]
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    var u = new Uri("https://{org}.visualstudio.com");

                VssCredentials c = new VssCredentials(new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, "personal access token"));
                var connection = new VssConnection(u, c);
                var workItemTracking = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
                JsonPatchDocument jsonPatchOperations = new JsonPatchDocument();


                    var attachmentresult = workItemTracking.CreateAttachmentAsync(stream,fileName:"test.pptx").Result;
                    jsonPatchOperations.Add(new JsonPatchOperation() {
                        Operation=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Patch.Operation.Add,
                        Path= "/relations/-",
                        Value = new
                        {
                            rel="AttachedFile",
                            url=attachmentresult.Url,
                            attributes = new { comment = "Adding new attachment" }
                        }
                    });
                   var workitemupdated= workItemTracking.UpdateWorkItemAsync(jsonPatchOperations, 1111).Result;
```

The related references are in [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient) package

Answer (score 1):

The attachments added to the bug work item are added locally, so I think you should first download the varbinary data to the local and then add it as an attachment to the bug work item.

About downloading varbinary data from sql server,you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516606/download-varbinary-data-from-sql-server) or through Google.

About adding attachments to an work item using C#,you can refer to the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189394/how-to-add-attachments-to-an-existing-work-item-in-azure-devops-using-c-sharp) you created earlier.